# How to set two button in a line without using grid in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

how to set two buttons in a line without using grid in windows phone

two controls within single line

```
  <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
            <Button Content="-" Width="80"  />
            <Button Content="+" Width="80" />  
  </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use orientation property of stackPanel

> Orientation="Horizontal"

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="-" Width="80"  />
            <Button Content="+" Width="80" />  
  </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

use orientation property of stackPanel

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="-" Width="80"  />
            <Button Content="+" Width="80" />  
  </StackPanel>
```